# Logstash cannot recognise log time

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm new to the ELK stack however after reading the documentation I am still unable to get logstash to recognise the custom time for

Logs look like this

```
2014-11-30 03:30:01.000118,122.99.34.242,123.56.212.1,44,u,q,NA,0       ? a.root-servers.net A
```

My logstash filter is this

```
filter {
    date {
            #2014-11-30 03:30:01.000118,122.99.34.242,123.56.212.1,44,u,q,NA,0       ? a.root-servers.net A
            match => ["timestamp" , "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
            locale => "en"
    }
}
```

However when i run it though this config file through with the log file it doesnt appear to recognise the match i have define

```
{
   "message" => "2014-11-30 03:30:01.011895,123.52.36.153,213.55.121.1,55,u,q,NA,0\t? mobile-collector.newrelic.com A\t",
  "@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2014-12-03T03:09:49.857Z",
      "type" => "syslog",
      "host" => "0.0.0.0",
      "path" => "/var/log/dns/2014-11-30_0335_dnsparse.log"
}
```

I'm running "logstash 1.4.2-modified"

For completeness here is my entire logstash config

```
input {
    file {
            path => "/var/log/dns/*.log"
            type => "dns_parselog"
            start_position => beginning
    }
}

filter {
    date {
            #2014-11-30 03:30:01.000118,122.99.34.242,123.56.212.1,44,u,q,NA,0       ? a.root-servers.net A
            match => ["timestamp" , "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
            locale => "en"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
            host => localhost
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're asking the date filter to parse a field named "timestamp", but there is no such field. Start by extracting the timestamp in the message to a separate field, then use the date filter.

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}"]
  }
  date {
    match => ["timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"]
    remove_field => ["timestamp"]
  }
}
```

You'll want to add additional patterns to the grok expression to extract additional fields, but that's out of the scope of this question.